# How do you delete a tweet in TweetDeck (web version)?

Tags: twitter, tweetdeck

I want to delete a tweet in the web version of TweetDeck.

[image]

How can I delete a tweet? Where is the delete tweet icon or menu entry? I found many old howtos that do no longer apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the right-most icon -

[image]

And I hope @Newsweek is your own account. Or else you cannot delete the tweet.

Comment: No, i am not newsweek, I should have taken my own tweet for an example better.